# Filter an array in underscorejs by using another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

```
var list1 =[{user: "A", id: 'a'},
            {user: "B", id: 'b'},
            {user: "C", id: 'c'},
            {user: "D", id: 'd'},
            {user: "E", id: 'e'}];
var list2 = ["A","B","C"];
```

I have above two arrays and i want to filter list1 by using list2. My output should be [{id: 'a'},{id: 'b'},{id: 'c'}] or only ['a','b','c'].

I am doing following way to filter but not getting any result. What is wrong here?

```
var ids = _.filter(list1, function(id) { 
                    _.each(list2, function(name){ 
                            return id.user === name; 
                    }); 
          });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you could just filter the array and then map `id` to the result set.

```js
var list1 =[{ user: "A", id: 'a' }, { user: "B", id: 'b' }, { user: "C", id: 'c' }, { user: "D", id: 'd' }, { user: "E", id: 'e' }],
    list2 = ["A","B","C"],
    result = list1.filter(a => list2.includes(a.user)).map(a => a.id);
    
console.log(result);
```

With underscore's

- [`_.pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) for getting the value of a property,
- [`_.contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) for a check if the values is in an array and
- [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) for returning a sub set.

```js
var list1 =[{ user: "A", id: 'a' }, { user: "B", id: 'b' }, { user: "C", id: 'c' }, { user: "D", id: 'd' }, { user: "E", id: 'e' }],
    list2 = ["A","B","C"],
    result = _.pluck(_.filter(list1, a => _.contains(list2, a.user)), 'id');
    
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _.pluck and _.contains are no longer available in newer versions. so use `_.map` instead of `_.pluck` and `_.map` instead of `_.contains`

Comment: @emkarachchi, great to know. you could edit this answer, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

The function inside `filter` should return a boolean meaning "keep it" or "don't keep it". `each` performs an operation on each element of an array, but doesn't return anything.

A simply fix is to use `find` instead of `each`:

```
var ids = _.filter(list1, function(id) {      
  return _.find(list2, function(name) { return id.user === name; });
});
```

To extract only the ids, use `map`:

```
ids = ids.map(function(user){ return user.id });
```